# C# : Return of Null-Conditional Operator for Objects

Tags: reference, operator-keyword

Let's say I have the following class :

```
class Class1
{
    public string MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

Then, let's make a little test :

```
Class1 myClass1 = null;
Console.WriteLine(myClass1?.MyProp ?? "Ohoh"); // Print "Ohoh"
Console.WriteLine(myClass1.MyProp ?? "Ohoh");  // Null Exception
```

What is the type of the return of "myClass1?." ?
Why do I have "Ohoh" printed ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(.?) is used to test for null before performing a member access. It returns null if checking for null before accessing sayd that operand is null

?? operator returns left operand if it is not null, or right operand if left is null

So, in second line check for null fails, (.?) operator returns null and ?? operator returns right operand.

in third line you try to access property without checking for null, and you have null reference exception

Comment: You said "(.?) operator returns null ". Then, if it returns null, .MyProp should throw an exception. But here, it's not throwing anything.

Comment: Oups, ok.
I made a mistake, you are right.
It's "myClass1?.MyProp" that returns null, not ""myClass1?.".